# Parallel animation of two elements where width of one depends on final width of other

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Let's suppose we have two `div`s, and the 2nd `div` has to be as wide as the first. If I just get the first `width` and set the 2nd `div` with `.css` property, it works, because the `width` of first `div` is known. But with `.animate`, its not known. I must wait until the first `.animate` has run.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JBJp8/3/)

```
#a
{
    background-color: green;
}

#b
{
    background-color: red;
}

<span id="a">aaa aa a a a a a aa</span>
<br />
<span id="b">bbb</span>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // this works, but I dont want this
    $('#b').width ($('#a').width());

    // and this WONT work, because widht of #a is not yet calculated    
    $('#b').animate({
        'width' : $('#a').width()
    }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: something like that, but the #a will be .animate-d too, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question fully, this is more closer to what you want than the sample I had posted in comments earlier.

The `step` function is useful for enabling custom animation types or altering the animation as it is occurring (that is dynamically setting `width` of `#b` based on the current `width` of `#a` as it is also being animated). The `now` variable would have the calculated width of `#a` at each step.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#a').animate({
    'width': $('#c').width()
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    queue: false,
    step: function(now, fx) {
      $('#b').animate({
        'width': now
      }, {
        duration: 2500,
        queue: false
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#a {
  background-color: green;
}
#b {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="c">Some very lengthy content</span>
<br/>
<span id="a">Some lengthy content</span>

<br/>
<span id="b">Some content</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I hadn't understand question as well, but hope you need code like this:

HTML

```
<div id="firstDiv"></div>
<div id="secondDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#firstDiv
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: Green;
}
#secondDiv
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var firstWidth = "300px"
    $("#firstDiv").animate({width: firstWidth}, 1000)
    $("#secondDiv").animate({width: firstWidth}, 1000 );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjMT9/).

Comment: that one is not bad, but I must do this at the same time

Comment: I have edited :) but I can't paste code into answer texboxt. It gaves error

Comment: The were html marcup, css and JQuery codes, I don't want to paste all of them

Comment: @FaridImranov: It is always better to post all parts of the code that has been modified. Else, the answer would lose its worth when for some reason the link is no longer active. Moreover, SO doesn't encourage link only answers.